# JAVA XML remove Node - only first appearance is removed

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have this method for removing a node from an XML file:

```
public static void deleteElement(Document doc, String elementType, String tagName, String valueToCheck) {
        // <elementType>
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(elementType);
        System.out.println("NODES: "+nodes.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element person = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            // <tagName>
            Element name = (Element) person.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0);
            String pName = name.getTextContent();
            System.out.println(pName);
            if (pName.equals(valueToCheck)) {
                person.getParentNode().removeChild(person);
                System.out.println("match" + pName);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("NODES AFTER DELETE: "+nodes.getLength());
    }
```

Where i specify the root element, the tag to be checked and the value to be checked.

On my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <book>
      <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Person 1</name>
      </person>
      <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Person 2</name>
      </person>
      <person>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Person 3</name>
      </person>
      <person>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Person 3</name>
      </person>
    </book>
```

the output after executing the method with the parameters `person`, `name`, `Person 3` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
  <person>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Person 1</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Person 2</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>Person 3</name>
  </person>
</book>
```

I.e. only the first appearance was removed... any ideas why?

Comment: what is the value of elementType in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM node lists are *live*, in other words when you modify the document the node list changes to reflect the new state of the document. During the third iteration of the loop you remove the first matching element (`item(2)`) from the document. This also causes it to disappear from the `nodes` list, shortening the list by one node and shifting everything after it up one index - the second matching node becomes `item(2)`. Then you increment `i` and find it is `== nodes.getLength()` and the loop ends without processing the last entry.

To avoid this, iterate backwards:

```
for (int i = nodes.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```